# Filter URL specified in CSS (but SVG is in HTML doc) not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, svg-filters

The effect uses an SVG/Filter which is in the HTML document. It is then specified in an external CSS document using `filter:url('#noise') contrast(110%);`.

The effect works in Chrome/Firefox (all I've tested so far) on Mac OS but fails when viewed in the latest Safari on Mac OS + iOS. It seems odd this fails in modern browsers, especially on iOS. So I wondered is there a fix, workaround or am I just plain missing something?

Maybe the simple noise effect is a bit OTT for a SVG/Filter. And Safari could be served a `background-image` instead, if possible?

To credit the person who created this example, this is the original CodePen: https://codepen.io/inegoita/pen/PrBOYM

Thanks in advance!

```css
:root{
  background:radial-gradient(#1f0e30 0%,#030016 40%) -10vw 20vh no-repeat #030016;
  
  filter:url('#noise') contrast(110%);
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  position:absolute;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'RoadRage';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('RoadRage'), url('http://coding-dude.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/Road_Rage.woff') format('woff') ;
}

.centered{
  position:absolute;
  left:50vw;
  top:50vh;
  transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.road-rage{
  font-family:'Road Rage';
  font-size:10rem;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height:75%;
  display:inline-block;
  transform:rotate(-5deg);
  color:#fe417b;
  background:#fe417b;
  width:120%;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  filter:url(#softGlow);
  z-index:-1;
}

.road-rage.offset{
  margin-left:3rem;
}

.shine:after{
/*   text-shadow:0 0 10px #fe417b, 0 0 100px #fe417b; */
  content:attr(data-text);
  background-image:linear-gradient(0deg,transparent 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 35%,transparent 60%);
  mix-blend-mode:soft-light;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: 100% 50%;
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered"><span class="road-rage shine" data-text="road">road</span><br/><span class="road-rage offset shine" data-text="rage">rage</span></div>

<a style="color:white;position:absolute;bottom:0" href="http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/css/svg-filters/">SVG Filters</a>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    
    <filter id="noise" x="0vw" y="0vh" width="100vw" height="100vh">
      <feFlood flood-color="#808080" result="neutral-gray" />      
      <feTurbulence in="neutral-gray" type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.8" numOctaves="10" stitchTiles="stitch" result="noise"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="noise" type="saturate" values="0" result="destaturatedNoise"></feColorMatrix>
      <feComponentTransfer in="desaturatedNoise" result="theNoise">
        <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 0 0.2 0"></feFuncA>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="theNoise" mode="soft-light" result="noisy-image"/>      
    </filter>
 
    
    <filter id="softGlow" height="300%" width="300%" x="-75%" y="-75%">
        <!-- Thicken out the original shape -->
        <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="2" in="SourceAlpha" result="thicken" />

        <!-- Use a gaussian blur to create the soft blurriness of the glow -->
        <feGaussianBlur in="thicken" stdDeviation="10" result="blurred" />

        <!-- Change the colour -->
        <feFlood flood-color="rgba(254,65,123,0.8)" result="glowColor" />

        <!-- Color in the glows -->
        <feComposite in="glowColor" in2="blurred" operator="in" result="softGlow_colored" />

        <!--    Layer the effects together -->
        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode in="softGlow_colored"/>
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </feMerge>

    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Safari doesn't support SVG filters accessed vis a CSS filter when there are certain primitives in the filter - feComposite, for example. If you want this effect you'll have to do it all inside an inline SVG.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMullany! Would you suggest if the effects are important, just stay away from using this method? By inline SVG, do you mean put the text + CSS within the `<svg></svg>`?

Comment: Yes - apply the filter on a SVG text element. The work here is that a lot of that CSS isn't supported on SVG sub-elements - particularly in Safari, so you'll have some work to do to find replacements.

Comment: in some cases, adding translate3d(0,0,0) solves some filter problems in safari, did not try your case.